# Is there a way in Snowflake that I can get only the columns in a table that have values?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Some tables are very wide but many of the columns are just empty. I'm looking for something to return me only the columns that have values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE remove_empty_columns(sql_query VARCHAR)
  RETURNS STRING NOT NULL
  LANGUAGE javascript
  execute as owner
  AS
  $$
  var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: "CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_TABLE AS " + SQL_QUERY});
  var rs = stmt.execute();
  
  // Get the result set metadata
 var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TEMP_TABLE'"});
  var rs = stmt.execute();
 
  // Initialize an array to store the non-empty column names
  var non_empty_cols = [];
  
  // Loop through the result set and check for non-empty columns
  while (rs.next()) {
      var col_value = rs.getColumnValue(1);
      var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: "SELECT distinct " + col_value + " FROM TEMP_TABLE"});
      var nr_values = stmt.execute();
      if (nr_values.next()) {
      if (nr_values.getColumnValue(1) !== null || nr_values.getRowCount() > 1) {
        non_empty_cols.push(col_value);
      }
    }
  }

  // Build a new SQL query that only includes non-empty columns
  var new_query = "SELECT ";
  for (var i = 0; i < non_empty_cols.length; i++) {
    new_query += non_empty_cols[i];
    if (i < non_empty_cols.length - 1) {
      new_query += ", ";
    }
  }
  new_query += " FROM (" + SQL_QUERY + ") t";

  return new_query;
$$
```

Use the above stored procedure, and call it like this, where the parameter is an SQL Query:

```
CALL remove_empty_columns('SELECT * FROM DB_DW_PROD.SC_ODS.ODS_SUBSCR_INFO')
```